# Two questions about the "No space left on device" error of my vagrant vm

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I git cloned a project which uses Vagrant. I used to have everything working with Vagrant, I mean I run `vagrant up` & `vagrant ssh`, then start my web application project.

Today, I ssh to my vagrant virtual box by `vagrant ssh`. Then under the virtual box, I import my database by:

```
$ mysql -u root -p mydb < /vagrant/db.sql
```

After a while, I restarted my MacBook, then I bring up vagrant VM by command `vagrant up` under project folder. I start getting following error:

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:398:in `await_response_state': scp: /tmp/vagrant-network-entry: No space left on device (RuntimeError)
```

**My first question:**
Is it because I import database to it so the space is running out?

(I know by googling, there are answers on how to increase space on Vagrant vm, but that's not I want)

**My second question:**
How can I revert back to the state when I haven't imported the database? Imaging now I am not able to bring up (neither can SSH to)the Vagrant vm due to the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Open the VM in virtual box capture keyboard and drop database from there. You can't revert if you don't have a backup.